# How to docker compose grpc both client and server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, grpc

Im trying create docker-compose yaml file with configuration of grpc port but i have no i idea how to it. i research but not able to find any sample or to read by the this spring boot - grpc java

This configuration is working but grpc port is not showing if i run in termminal.

Im trying create docker-compose yaml file with configuration of grpc port but i have no i idea how to it. i research but not able to find any sample or to read by the this spring boot - grpc java

This configuration is working but grpc port is not showing if i run in termminal.

```
//appilication.yaml

spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:${MYSQL_PORT:3306}/dbpoc?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true
    username: ${MYSQL_USER:root}
    password: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD:root}
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
    
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
      continue-on-error: true
      
  mvc:
   throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
  web:
    resources:
      add-mappings: false


grpc:
  server:
     port: 9090
```

```
//docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'

networks:
    cartservice-net:
      driver: bridge

services:

    
  cartservice:
    image: cartservice:latest
    container_name: cartservice
    depends_on:
      - cart-mysqldb
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - cartservice-net
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: cart-mysqldb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306

  cart-mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: cart-mysqldb
    ports: 
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - cartservice-net
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbpoc
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

```
//Dockerfile

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to your cartservice service the port tag so that you specify that this port needs to be exposed.

```
//docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'

networks:
    cartservice-net:
        driver: bridge

services:


    cartservice:
      image: cartservice:latest
      container_name: cartservice
      depends_on:
        - cart-mysqldb
      restart: always
      build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports: 
        - "9090:9090"
      networks:
        - cartservice-net
      environment:
        MYSQL_HOST: cart-mysqldb
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_PORT: 3306

    cart-mysqldb:
      image: mysql:8.0.28
      restart: unless-stopped
      container_name: cart-mysqldb
      ports: 
        - "3307:3306"
      networks:
        - cartservice-net
      cap_add:
        - SYS_NICE
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dbpoc
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

Comment: If that works, please consider upvote , mark as answered, etc...

Comment: Sure, I mark as answered but i cannot upvote since im new and i need 15 reputation to upvote. Thanks again